# Facebook with dotnetopenauth

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-c#-sdk, dotnetopenauth

I have created an App on facebook and I am using this app to authorize an user via dotnetopenauth.

Here I would pass APPID and APPSECRET and get the token which would be used to call Facebook Graph to get facebook user details. 
If I'm doing this for the first time, user would be asked to enter username/passowrd on the Facebook website and then the session is created in the browser and it will redirect to my website as a Facebook user. This means that if I open a new tab in the current window and open facebook, user will see his/her page directly without asking for username/password. - this is obvious and understandable.

```
 // code
 request = WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(strAccessToken)); 
 response = request.GetResponse();
```

My query is:
After the scenario above, if user logs out from Facebook website OR I close the browser window, the facebook session is lost. However, I still have the access token (string in the above code) that I got while authenticating. 
So, As of this moment I am not storing any user information from Facebook (not even cookies or anything else). I am just requesting user to authorize my application as a Facebook user. When user does that, I get the access token which I can use it to make calls to Graph and REST APIs. This access token usually remains same, so I really dont need to pass the applicaition id and secret to get the token next time onwards. Actually I can request the graph APIs and REST APIs with the stored token and request user details. I have tested this and works fine.

What I am looking for is, if user opens www.facebook.com, user should see his/her personal facebook page which obviosuly is possible only if I have a session in the current browser. Hence, my question was: how do I use my access token OR what call should I make with my access token so that I can set the browser session for the facebook user? Is it possible technically?

Regards,
AG

Answer (score 0):

No.  Your access token is used by your web server to call facebook.  It's impossible (and undesirable) for this to impact the user's browser in a way that would set a facebook.com cookie so that the user would be implicitly logged into Facebook by your use of the access token.